# Why doesnt this react component recheck the if statement in render i.e after state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, state, render

I am doing a fetch request in componentDidMount and am using it to change the state of the urls.
the problem is that it doesnt recheck the condition give inside render after the state changes. why is that happening?
basically, after the state changes I want to create the canvases dynamically based on the data in urls and then use the canvas to 
convert pdf to image.

here's the react component

```
export default class ShowSplitPdf extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            loading:true,
            imgsrc : []
        }
    }

    pdfConversion = ()=>{
        if(window.PDFJS){
            console.log(this.state);
            let urls = this.state.urls;
            for(var i = 0;i<urls.length;i++){
                let newurl = urls[i];
                //let newurl = 'http://172.104.60.70/st_old/uploads/defaultdocs/7/split/1527165241-42557/1_1527165241-42557.pdf';

               this.pdfLoop(newurl,i);
            }

            }
    }

    pdfLoop = (item,index) => {
        var that = this;
        PDFJS.getDocument(item).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(pdf) {
             //
             // Fetch the first page
             console.log('url is : ',item);
             pdf.getPage(1).then(function getPageHelloWorld(page) {
               var scale = 0.5;
               var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);


                   let cref = 'canvas'+index;
                   let imgref ='img'+index;
                   console.log('cref no : ',cref);
                   console.log('img no : ',imgref);

                   // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                   //
                   var canvas = that.canvasRefs[cref];
                   //let imagez = that.imageRefs[imgref];
                   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                   context.globalcompositeoperation = 'source-over';
                  // context.fillStyle = "#fff";
                  //draw on entire canvas
                  //context.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
                   canvas.height = viewport.height;
                   canvas.width = viewport.width;

                    //imagez.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                   //
                   // Render PDF page into canvas context
                   //
                   //page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport});
                   var task = page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport})
              task.promise.then(function(){
                //console.log(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
                let imgItem = {imgref:canvas.toDataURL('image/png')}
                let newState = that.state.imgsrc.concat(imgItem);
                that.setState({
                    imgsrc:newState
                });
                //imagez.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
              });

             });
           });
       }


    componentDidMount(){
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("filepath",this.props.item.pdfname); 
        let editUrl = devUrl+'trip/getpdfSplitViewtripdoc?json=true';
        //this.setState({showSplitFiles:true,loading:true});
        var that = this;
        fetch(editUrl, {
          method: "post" ,
          credentials:'include',
          body:formData
        }).then(function(response) {

          return response.json();
        }).then(function(data) {
            let urls = [];
            for(var i = 0;i<data.files.length;i++){
                let fileurl = pdfUrl+'split/'+data.dir+'/'+data.files[i];
                urls.push(fileurl);
            }
            if(that._isMounted){
                that.setState({
                    //splitpdfData:data,
                    urls
                });
            }
        }).catch((err)=>console.log(err)); 
    }

    render(){
        let canvasDiv = [];
        if(this.state.urls && this.state.urls.length>0){
            this.state.urls.map((item,index)=>{
              let canv =  <canvas key={index} style={{display:'none'}} ref={(ref) => this.canvasRefs[`canvas${index}`] = ref} > </canvas>;
              canvasDiv.push(canv);
            });
        }
        if(this.state.imgsrc.length>0){
            this.state.imgsrc.map((item,index)=>{
                console.log('item is : ',item);
            });
        }
        return(
            <div>
            show pdf images here
            {this.state.loading?<Spin style={{width:'100%',margin:"0 auto"}} tip="Loading Pdf..."/>:''}
            {canvasDiv.length>0?canvasDiv:''}
            {canvasDiv.length>0?this.pdfConversion():''}
                </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: in your code you don't have a state variable `urls` and you are trying to access it in your `render` and `componentDidMount`

Comment: i am setting it in componentDidMount. it is there

Comment: but you don't have it initialized  in your constructor

Comment: ok. i have done that before and it didnt make a difference. anyways. let me try initializing it there.

Comment: nope. that didnt help either

Comment: try putting console.logs in your if conditions then you can know if that block of executing the second time around

Comment: i have done that and it is not executing the 2nd time. and actually i just saw that the state is not changing at all. I am getting the values but state doesnt change. not sure. why

Comment: I think i got it. 
the state was not setting because the ismounted was coming up as undefined. have fixed it now.
anyways. thanks. i noticed it only after your comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172572/discussion-between-aravind-reddy-and-faraz).

Comment: no. it's okay. my problem is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `that._isMounted` is `undefined` and you are not changing the state when you get the response from your backend. You should manage this variable using the callbacks like this:

```
componentDidMount() { 
  this._isMounted = true;
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this._isMounted = false;
}
```

Try to add a `console.log` before changing the state.